# removing loops from octave code

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I am new to Octave and want to vectorize this kind of computation...

A and B are matrices that have the same number of rows, say m. Otherwise they have  arbitrary column size.

Let size(A, 2) = k, and size(B, 2) = l

The loop I want to vectorize.

```
 for t = 1:m
    ARP = ARP + A(t,:)' * B(t,:)
 end
```

Which is a sum of matrices size (kX1)X(1Xl) = kXl.

Finally ARP = 1/m * ARP

After some research I have wrote this 'solution' which balloons up the size of my matrices and in fact fails when the matrices get largish.

```
%Create copies of A stacked on top of each other to a depth of l
exA = repmat(A, l, 1);                     % (m * k)Xl

%Reshape it so that exA has each column of A cloned k times
exA = reshape(exA, m, k * l);              % mX(k * l)

%Create copies of B stacked next to each other to a width k
exB = repmat(B, 1, k);                     % mX(l * k)

%Both matrices are now m X k*l so we can element-wise multiply
%and take the mean of the rows.


ARP = mean(exA .* exB, 1);   % 1X(k * l)

ARP = reshape(ARP, l, k)';
```

I am also aware that repmat can be replaced in vectorizations with bsxfun, although it is not clear how to implement bsxfun in this case. I appreciate any help that gets me to an optimized solution and also illustrates techniques for vectorization that I can study for similar problems.

Thanks in advance Mike

Comment: How about `ARP = A'*B`?

Comment: Thank you Divakar - very simple and obvious solution - after the fact.